# Parsing the value of a specific column in a database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called `cost_calc_date` of type `Date` in my database table named as account.

The value in a particular cell is `2018-03-20` which is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I need to return only the month, that is `03` as the output.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: What database you are talking about?

Comment: It's a postgresql database.

Comment: I have stored it as date. Following is the description of the table :

Create Table Account (lineId int Primary Key, accId int, versionNumber int, chargeableFte int, costCalcDate Date, isApproved BIT DEFAULT '1');

Comment: `DATE` columns don't have "a format". The value is stored in a binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
 SELECT MONTH(cost_calc_date) as 'Month'
 FROM account
```

Or this code:

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, cost_calc_date) AS 'Month' 
from account;
```

Comment: script only answers are not appreciated, please add some comments to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to get parts of a date (or timestamp) column.

To get the month, use:

```
extract(month from cost_calc_date);
```

This will return a number, e.g. `3`

Answer (score 0):

select datepart(mm,cost_calc_date)   from account